# JS check if page/content NOT contains

Tags: javascript, contain, innertext

I want to check if a page contains a specific word. And if it doesn't contain the word, it should to some action.

I only have the code for checking if the word is contained.

```
var bodyText = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var msg = "My word";

if (bodyText.indexOf(msg) > -1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = "http://contains.word";
    }, 1000);
}
```

But I want to change it to if it **NOT contains** it. Any solution?

Comment: `if (bodyText.indexOf(msg) == -1) {`?

Comment: `if (bodyText.indexOf(msg) === -1) {`?

Comment: do you mean like: `if(!(bodyText.indexOf(msg)>-1))` OR using the indexOf return value and checking such as: `if(bodyText.indexOf(msg)===-1)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple lookup of the `indexOf` function should provide you the answer...
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.
>
> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

If that isn't clear, what you're looking for is if `indexOf` returns -1.

Comment: He's already using `indexOf`. He wants to know how to invert the condition.

Comment: I've edited my post...but the quote should be enough to infer how to determine if the search string never occurs, without explicitly writing the code.